# Restrict Locator to a certain graphic inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I would like to restrict the Locator inside Manipulate to a certain graphic. For example if I display two graphs, I would like to be able to click on the right one and use this information in other places (for example in the title and the left graph). By design, `Manipulate` assigns the `Locator` to the **first** graphic object that it displays (see under [Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html)). How can this be overcome?

Here is an example snippet:

```
Manipulate[
 sin =
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}];
 cos = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
   PlotLabel -> "I would like to have the locator on this graph!", 
   ImageSize -> Medium, Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}];
 Column[{Style[StringForm["Title `1`", p], Large],
   Row[{sin, cos}]}, Center],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, ControlType -> Locator}]
```

[image: example output]

I know this can be done using `Dynamic`, but then I loose some features of manipulate, such as "Paste Snapshoot", "Make Bookmark" and `SaveDefinitions`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: I am replacing my first attempt with another. The locator-point in the right graph controls the information in the title as well as the point in the left graph.

The point on the right could be made to appear like a locator by replacing `Point` with an appropriate-looking graphics object.

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{Style[StringForm["Title `1`", Dynamic@pt], Large], 
       Row[{Plot[Cos[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
       Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Cos[First[pt]]}]]}, 
       ImageSize -> 300], 
       LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
         Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
         Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Sin[First[pt]]}]]}, 
         ImageSize -> 300, 
         PlotLabel -> "I would like to have the locator on this graph!"], 
       Appearance -> None]}]}, Center], {{pt, {0, 1}}, None}]
```

[image: locator on right]

---

**Note**

Normally one confines a Locator to a particular region using optional parameters in `LocatorPane`:

[image: LocatorPane instructions]

However, it is not necessary to do this above because the LocatorPane sits in a single cell in the table.  The locator cannot exceed the bounds of that cell.

Comment: I switched the sin and cos graphs, but the intent should be clear.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Do you perhaps have an idea, why the title is messed up, when you do "Paste snapshot"? (And why it works if I pout the `Dynamic` around `Style` instead of `pt`?

Comment: @Ajasja I'm not sure why you want to use "paste snapshot". What are you trying to paste, and where?

Comment: The paste snapshot is available when you click the + in the upper right corner of the manipulate pane. If I try to evaluate the new cell then the title does not seam to get the value. I want to use this to bookmark interesting parameter combinations as shown [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html) under "Bookmarking Combinations of Parameter Values"

Comment: Apparently, the rendering of the PlotLabel depends on activation of Style. Dynamic apparently ensures that it is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Overlay`:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Style[StringForm["Title `1`", Dynamic[p]], Large], Overlay[{
     Dynamic@
      Plot[Cos[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        "I would like to have the locator on this graph!",
       ImageSize -> Large, 
       Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}, 
       PlotRegion -> {{0.5, 1}, {0, 1}}],
     Dynamic@
      Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> Large, 
       Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]},
       PlotRegion -> {{0, .5}, {0, 1}}, 
       PlotLabel -> "Not on this graph!"]
     }, All, 1]}, Center],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, {-5, -1}, {5, 1}, ControlType -> Locator}]
```

**Edit**

[image: manipulate]

I added explicit `Dynamic` around objects depending on `p` to prevent sporadic loss of mouse tracking, and to hopefully speed up the response. The documentation for `Manipulate` states:

> In the form  {u,Locator}, the value of  u is a list giving  x and  y
>   coordinates. The coordinates refer either to the first graphic in 
>   expr, or range from 0 to 1 in each direction across  expr.

Here I'm relying on the coordinates of the first graphic in the `Overlay` expression.

What I did to arrange the graphics horizontally is simply to set their `PlotRegion` option to leave either the left or right half of the surrounding space empty. In the `Overlay`, they then fill the two halves to form what looks like a row.

Comment: Due to the way my other data is laid out I would like the locator be on the right. This works by setting  `Overlay[{sin, cos}]`, although I have no idea why. Also with `Overlay` manipulate seems to respond slower than with `LocatorPane`.

Comment: @Ajasja Yes, you're right about the speed. Honestly, I don't like Manipulate.

Comment: Yes, sadly I had a lot of problems as well. Although with a bit of tweaking and hacking and workarounds I get there eventually. I hope this will improve in mma 9 :)

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: the locator moves even if I click in the "Title" section, so it is not really restricted to the right plot region.

Comment: @shrx The locator **is** restricted to the right plot region. I just tried it. It does move to the **edge** of the region if you click as you describe, but it never leaves that region.

Comment: Yes, I thought it should not react to clicks outside its region.