# Manipulating several values from the same interval

Tags: manipulate, locator

Some of my calculations depend on the choice of several values from the interval [-2, 2] (it is more or less interpolation of a fixed function using the points as parameters). I want to create a dynamic control for them. The ideal thing to have would be a Slider with multiple positions to move, or a Locator on a line. As for now, I have tried to implement the second variant:

```
Manipulate[
  points[[All, 2]] = Table[0, {5}];
  Plot[points, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 1/100, AspectRatio -> 0.01],
  {{points, ({#, 0} &) /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5}] }, Locator}]
```

That works, but with quirks: locator panes still can be lifted visibly higher or lower than the base line. Sure, they fall back immediately due to `points[[All, 2]] = Table[0, {5}]` line, but I hope there is a better solution. Is there?

Comment: See [1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/locatorpane-and-plotrange), [2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/how-to-dynamically-update-locator-constraints), [3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13797/how-do-i-constrain-the-region-where-i-can-drag-a-locator), [4)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/restrict-locator-to-a-certain-graphic-inside-manipulate), [5)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve).  Almost an exact duplicate, but this admits a solution the others do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix: if you set the option

```
AspectRatio -> 10^-10
```

then it's impossible to see the slight jiggling of the locators as you move them with the mouse. You can also make it look like anything you wish. For instance, if you want it to be ugly, you can define

```
g = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}];
```

and then add

```
Appearance -> g
```

to your Locator definition. In this way, you can "build" the multi-slider you are asking for. if you are good with graphics, you could even make it look just like a slider.

Comment: Yeah, that's better, but I still hope for the more "conceptual" way to make a manipulator for several variables from the same interval.

Comment: Well, it seems there is no radically better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quite natural way built into `Manipulate` and `LocatorPane`. Use the two arguments
`...{-2., 0.}, {2., 0.},...`
below to set the domain for the `Locator`s.  This lets the x coordinate range from `-2` to `2` and the y coordinate range from `0` to, well, `0` -- that is, it can't move vertically.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Times @@ (x - First /@ points)], {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{points, ({#, 0} &) /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5}]}, {-2., 0.}, {2., 0.}, Locator}]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Here's another way.  Use a `LocatorPane` and the second argument to `Dynamic` to set all of the second coordinates to `0`.  Here I have put a little grid above the `Locator` graphic to show the x, y coordinates.  Of course the grid could be anything.  So this example shows how to integrate ths sort of `Locator` control into `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Dynamic @ Grid @ Transpose @ points, 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[points, (points = {#, 0} & /@ First /@ #) &],
    Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.1, .1}}, Axes -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 300, Ticks -> {Automatic, None}]
    ]
   }],
 {{points, ({#, 0} &) /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5}]}, ControlType -> None}]
```

[image: Another Manipulate]

---

Edit:

Here's a variation on the preceding `Manipulate` in which the `Locator` control appears in the control area.  This is perhaps a more natural way to incorporate a "multi-slider."

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Dynamic @ Grid @ Map[Pane[#, {60, 12}] &, Transpose@points, {2}]
   }],
 {{points, ({#, 0} &) /@ Round[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5}], .001]}, 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[points, (points = {#, 0} & /@ First /@ #) &],
     Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-.1, .1}}, Axes -> True, 
       ImageSize -> 300, Ticks -> {Automatic, None}],
     Appearance -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], LightGray, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]
     ] &}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate with multi-slider control]