# LocatorPane in Manipulate blocks interaction with other graphics

Tags: plotting, manipulate, interactive

I have a `Manipulate` that uses `LocatorPane` on a `ContourPlot` to move some a `Sphere` around a `Plot3D`.

If I specify that a `Locator` control should be used for the pane variable `p` it the sphere moves around. However, I can not rotate the 3d plot.

If I specify a `None` for the pane variable `p` then I can rotate the 3d plot but the sphere is not linked to the locator on the contour plot.

Below is a minimal example. I am uses the `Column` as I have some dynamic tables sharing the space of the controls (not included).

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{
   LocatorPane[p,
    ContourPlot[x y z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> Medium
     ]],
   Show[{
     Plot3D[ x y z,  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
      MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
      PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> Medium],
     Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
       Sphere[{First@p, Last@p, z First@p Last@p + .05}, .05],
       InfiniteLine[{First@p, Last@p, z First@p Last@p + .05}, {0, 0, 1}]}]
     }]
   }],
 Column[{
   Control@{{z, .5}, 0 + $MachineEpsilon, 1},
   Control@{{p, {0.5, 0.5}}, Locator}
   }]
 ]
```

I would like the interactivity to both move the sphere from the contour plot and rotate the 3d plot.  Ideas?

10.3 Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

PS: I also noticed that when I move the locator both of the plots recalculate. I thought my code would result in the plots only recalculating when `z` is updated. I can ask a separate question if this is too out of scope for a paired answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic@p, 
    ContourPlot[x y z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
     ImageSize -> Medium]], 
   Show[{Plot3D[x y z, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
       MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
       ImageSize -> Medium], 
      Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
        Sphere[{First@p, Last@p, z First@p Last@p + .05}, .05], 
        InfiniteLine[{First@p, Last@p, z First@p Last@p + .05}, {0, 0, 1}]}]}]}], 
 {{z, .5}, 0 + $MachineEpsilon, 1},
 {{p, {0.5, 0.5}}, ControlType -> None}]
```

The OP's declaration `Control@{{p, {0.5, 0.5}}, Locator}` causes `Manipulate` effectively to wrap the whole output with a `LocatorPane[Dynamic[p], <body>]`, which controls the variable `p`.  This locator pane captures all mouse-clicks on the output.  By changing the type to `None`, there is no automatically created control; rather, `p` is changed by the explicit `Dynamic@p` I added inside the `LocatorPane` in the body of the OP's `Manipulate`.  This restricts the scope of the `ClickPane`/`EventHandler` used by `LocatorPane` to be just the `ContourPlot` instead of the whole output.  Thus mouse-clicks outside the `ContourPlot` are passed to other handlers, like the FE one that rotates 3D graphics.

Comment: Yes, very much! What did you do?

Comment: I see you added some `Dynamic`s but don't understand why they are needed in `Manipulate` for this particular problem.  May you elaborate in your answer.

Comment: That does help explain things. `Manipulate` is a mysterious tool at times.  I'll let this sit for a bit just in case.

Comment: @Edmund You can see the two locators by adding `Appearance -> Style["\[MathematicaIcon]", Large, Red]` to the `LocatorPane` or the control spec.  (It's easier to see if you add it to the `LocatorPane` as the locator created by `Manipulate` sits on top. I think there may be an explanation on site about why the first graphics is chosen to constrain the locator.  I'll see if I can find it.)

Comment: @Edmund Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/restrict-locator-to-a-certain-graphic-inside-manipulate